# Ctrl-Enter for Midnight Commander not working in X terminals in Fedora, working in OpenSuse

Tags: fedora, terminal, opensuse, konsole, mc

I like Midnight Commander. Might have to do with starting with DOS machines in the early 90s in Russia, but now I just really like the integration of the command line with a two-panel file list. And a key feature is that Ctrl+Enter copies the name of the currently selected file or directory into the command line, without starting it.

Unfortunately, on Fedora (26 and 27) this fails in Konsole and, apparemntly, in all other X-based terminals too. It does work in the virtual console I get py pressing Ctrl-Alt-F3.

On OpenSuse Leap (42.1, 42.2, 42.3) the Ctrl+Enter functionality works perfectly. And I could not work out any difference. (I use KDE on both, which, as far as I understand, means that on Fedora I have X.org, not Wayland).

How can I make Ctrl+Enter work on Fedora? Alternatively if this is impossible, is there a way to reassign the very useful functionality to some other key combination in Midnight Commander?

(I would also consider alternatives to Midnight Commander itself, but on;y those running in a console window, and it seems there aren't any. I don't need a graphical two-panel file manager, as I use MC to assist in crafting commands quickly).

Comment: As a replacement there are also: `Ctrl+x t` (2-event sequence), `Ctrl+Alt+j`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr: Get used to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (a.k.a. <kbd>ESC</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>) instead.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> generates the exact same sequence in terminal emulators as <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so there's no way for an app to distinguish these two. Well, no way by looking at the input stream it receives from the terminal emulator.

`mc` has an interesting feature called "X11 support". It does not only look at the bytes it receives from the terminal emulator, but (if this support is compiled in, and if X11 connection is available runtime) queries the X11 server for the state of the modifier keys.

So basically it goes like: "Wow, I received an Enter from the terminal emulator. Hey, X11 server, is Ctrl pressed now?"

There are multiple ways this might not work for you.

Fedora's `mc` may have been compiled without X11 support, I don't know. Check the output of `mc --version`, does it contain "With support for X11 events"?

`su`, `sudo`, `screen`, `tmux`, `ssh` or similar tools can also break this functionality in case the X11 connection isn't available inside them (e.g. credentials not properly set up / forwarded by `su` or `sudo`; `screen` or `tmux` being detached and reattached from another X server; display not forwarded by `ssh`).

The feature doesn't work on Wayland either. I suspect it cannot be implemented in Wayland due to its security model, or at least not without some plugin/extension to some core Wayland component. But even if the state of modifiers could be detected, it's not yet done in `mc`.

Comment: Thanks! Alt+Enter works and that's enough for me right now.

Comment: In my case suggested solution do not work (NixOS 19.09). My mc installation `With support for X11 events`. But `Alt+Enter` produces nothing. At the same time all other `Alt+` combinations do work (`Alt+a`, `Alt+Shift+h`, `Alt+i`, etc).

Comment: @egmont If Ctrl-Enter is the same as Enter for mc under Wayland, how come "Ctrl-x, t" is working? Following your logic, it'd be an equivalent of simply "x, t".

Comment: `Enter` and `Ctrl+Enter` generate the same sequence. `X` and `Ctrl+X` don't. They are different to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

We still don't have a replacement for **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** in MC on Wayland.

So lacking one, I suggest to use **Alt-m** instead. And because *Enter* is the same as *Ctrl-m*, this means we would have:

- **Alt-Ctrl-m**, ie. **Alt-Enter**, for *Paste file name*.
- **Alt-m** for *Paste full path name*.

Note that by default *Alt-m* is assigned to the *Mail* action, so we will lose that mapping but it looks like a winning deal.

Here a (replayable) script to apply this new mapping in the default keymap (file `/etc/mc/mc.keymap`):

```bsh
sudo sed -ri '/PutCurrentFullSelected/s/=( alt-m;)?/= alt-m;/' /etc/mc/mc.default.keymap
sudo sed -ri '/Mail = alt-m/s/= alt-m/=/;' /etc/mc/mc.default.keymap
```

Or the patch:

```
diff --git a/mc/mc.default.keymap b/mc/mc.default.keymap
--- a/mc/mc.default.keymap
+++ b/mc/mc.default.keymap
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@ Shell = ctrl-o
 PutCurrentPath = alt-a
 PutOtherPath = alt-shift-a
 PutCurrentSelected = alt-enter; ctrl-enter
-PutCurrentFullSelected = ctrl-shift-enter
+PutCurrentFullSelected = alt-m; ctrl-shift-enter
 ViewFiltered = alt-exclamation
 Select = kpplus
 Unselect = kpminus
@@ -313,7 +313,7 @@ Help = f1
 Refresh = ctrl-l
 Goto = alt-l
 Sort = alt-t
-Mail = alt-m
+Mail =
 ParagraphFormat = alt-p
 MatchBracket = alt-b
 ExternalCommand = alt-u
```

Comment: How horrible. It used to work in Unity / X flawlessly.

Comment: Try these replacements: `Ctrl+x t` (2-event sequence), `Ctrl+Alt+j`.

Comment: @AleXoundOS Could you add some details/references for how 2-event sequences work? I.e. why `Ctrl+x t` works as `Alt+Enter`, why it's `Ctrl+x` and why it's `t`, and and what other keys could be used.